# How to solve "TypeError: expected string or buffer" when importing json data via api?

Tags: python, api, pandas

I'm trying to import JSON data via an API, and use the imported data to construct a DataFrame.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

api_username = 'acb'
api_password = 'efg'

germany_name = 'Germany'
germany_api_url = "https://api.country_data.com/stats/?country=" + germany_name + "&year=2014"
germany_api_resp = requests.get(germany_api_url,auth=(api_username,api_password))
germany_data_json = json.loads(germany_api_resp)
germany_frame = pd.DataFrame(germany_data_json['data']).set_index('tag')
```

`print(germany_frame)` shows me the desired DataFrame.

I want to repeat the process for many countries, not just `'Germany'`, so I created a country object like this:

```
class Country(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.api_url = "https://api.country_data.com/stats/?country=" + name + "&year=2014"
        self.api_resp = requests.get(self.api_url,auth=(api_username,api_password))
        self.data_json = json.loads(self.api_resp)
        self.frame = pd.DataFrame(self.data_json['data']).set_index('tag')
```

When I create my first object, like this:

```
Germany = Country('Germany')
```

I get an Error message:

```
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: is the api case sensitive? in which case try this `Germany = Country('germany')`

Comment: I still get the same problem, i'm afraid : (

Comment: please share the data you get in `self.api_resp`. comment the next 2 lines and re-run the code. print the `self.api_resp` object and see what is the content. Try to run the next two lines out the class separately and see why that is failing.

Comment: It is not easy to answer you because the url you gave us is not valid, and without it we can't test the code :/ I got myself errors about connections, and not the `TypeError` you described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't which version of Python you're using, and which version of `requests` but I recommend to you to update everything. Here is a error I found :

```
self.data_json = json.loads(self.api_resp)
```

You try to load in a json-way a `Response` from requests, so change it to :

```
self.data_json = self.api_resp.json()
```

I replaced your api url to another because yours is wrong and it works for me.

See ya !